# How do I get bootstrap slider to show full width inside div "well" with span text either side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

As per question title, I am using [bootstrap-slider.js](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) and I don't seem to be able to get away from the default of a fixed width. However I want it to expand with the screen width. Here is my code so far:

```
            <div class="well">
                <span>Least likely&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                <div class="slider slider-horizontal">
                    <input id="ex1" type="text" data-provide="slider" />
                </div>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Most likely</span>
            </div>
```

This looks like:
[image]

I have tried putting `style="width:100%"` on the input and again on the slider div, both with horrific results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flexbox. Also not required `&nsbp;` and added margin.

```js
// Without JQuery
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
  }
});
```

```css
#ex1Slider .slider-selection {
  background: #BABABA;
}

.dad {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  margin: auto 10px;
}

.bigchild {
  flex: 1;
}

div#ex1Slider.slider.slider-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<div class="well dad">
  <span class="child">Least likely</span>
  <div class="slider slider-horizontal bigchild">
    <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" />
  </div>
  <span class="child">Most likely</span>
</div>
```